# how to put igraph edges in correct order

Tags: r, igraph

I have data frame with animal names:

```
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = c("dog", "cat", "bird", "mammal", "avis", "canis", "feline"),
    col2 = c("canis", "feline", "avis", "animal", "animal", "mammal", "mammal"))

library(igraph) 

species <- union(df$col2, df$col1)
df <- df[c('col2', 'col1')]
names(df) <- c('from', 'to')
species <- species[order(species)]
species <- sort(union(df$col2, df$col1))
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = species)
plot(g,vertex.size=2, vertex.label.dist=0.5, vertex.color="cyan", 
 edge.arrow.size=0.5, layout=layout.reingold.tilford(g))
```

After I run the code I get this diagram (image below). In data frame first 3 elements are `"dog", "cat", "bird"` while in graph they are `"bird", "dog", "cat"`. In short the order of the words gets reversed and I want them in that specific order without changing data frame.

[image]

To tell igraph in what order I want my data to be represent I use `species <- species[order(species)]` this code line, while it works fine with data frames that have single letter it doesn't work with this or any other data frames that uses full words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your vertices are ordered according to the order in the vector `species`. Without the `vertices` argument, the order is according to the union elements in two columns data frame `df`.

```
> g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE)
> V(g)$name
[1] "canis"  "feline" "avis"   "animal" "mammal" "dog"    "cat"    "bird"  
> g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = species)
> V(g)$name
[1] "animal" "avis"   "bird"   "canis"  "cat"    "dog"    "feline" "mammal"
```

To solve your problem, sort the `species` vector according to the union of the two columns of `df`, *but take the second column first*. This way, the `"dog", "cat", "bird"` sequence leads off the `species` vector.

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("dog", "cat", "bird", "mammal", "avis", "canis", "feline"),
  col2 = c("canis", "feline", "avis", "animal", "animal", "mammal",     "mammal"))

library(igraph) 

df <- df[c('col2', 'col1')]
names(df) <- c('from', 'to')
species <- union(df$to, df$from) #NOTE do not sort the vector!
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = species)
plot(g,vertex.size=2, vertex.label.dist=0.5, vertex.color="cyan", 
     edge.arrow.size=0.5, layout=layout.reingold.tilford(g))
```

Now the vertices are ordered according to the order in species, putting `"dog", "cat", "bird"` first.

```
> species
[1] "dog"    "cat"    "bird"   "mammal" "avis"   "canis"  "feline" "animal"
> V(g)$name
[1] "dog"    "cat"    "bird"   "mammal" "avis"   "canis"  "feline" "animal"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

[image]

I just rearranged the order of the data e.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(from = c('animal', 'animal', 'mammal', 'mammal', 'avis', 'canis', 'feline'), 
                 to = c('mammal', 'avis', 'canis', 'feline', 'bird', 'dog', 'cat'))
```

igraph plots edges in the order of the `edgelist` which is different from the dataframe:

```
get.edgelist(g)
```

This is the info that needs to be changed. I have only created small graphs and always entered my data in the order I wanted, but I think this is what to investigate `set.edge.attribute()`.

Comment: I don't understand how to use `get.edgelist(g)` or `set.edge.attribute()` in my code